# Python Selenium cannot find an element on a page by xpath

Tags: python, selenium

I am using python and selenium to test some things with fantasy football. Here is my code so far (I just started).

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\202300Fontenot\\Desktop\\3\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://games.espn.com/ffl/signin?redir=http%3A%2F%2Fgames.espn.com%2Fffl%2Fclubhouse%3FseasonId%3D2018%26leagueId%3D49607%26teamId%3D4');
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
time.sleep(10)
search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="did-ui-view"]/div/section/section/form/section/div[1]/div/label/span[2]/input')
search_box.send_keys('email@icloud.com')
search_box.submit()
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

This just tries to enter an email address into the box. I am getting this error every time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\202300Fontenot\Desktop\3\ESPN.py", line 8, in <module>
    search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="did-ui-view"]/div/section/section/form/section/div[1]/div/label/span[2]/input')
  File "C:\Users\202300Fontenot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 393, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\202300Fontenot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 966, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\202300Fontenot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\202300Fontenot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="did-ui-view"]/div/section/section/form/section/div[1]/div/label/span[2]/input"}
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.92)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type=email]')`

Comment: never ever ever ever ever use xpath like `//*[@id="did-ui-view"]/div/section/section/form/section/div[1]/div/label/span[2]/input`. Because even you cannot see if it's correct or not, think about another person few months from now trying to debug your code... Always start from ID or unique attribute; if impossible, parent's id/unique attribute; if impossible, only then you need some more xpath magic, but even then in very minimal way. css selector suggested by Sers is fine, or you can do xpath `//input[@type='email']`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to switch to your iframe using its name:

> disneyid-iframe

Also if XPATH is not the only choice, you may use the CSS Selector:

> div.field-username-email input[type='email']

This will get the driver to find & fill your field.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the input you are trying to select exists inside of an iframe. You must first tell the driver to switch to the iframe and then execute the xpath selection.

```
driver.switch_to.frame("disneyid-iframe")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='email']").send_keys('email@icloud.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using XPath in python You need to provide the string for

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath
```

Example Code below

```
("//*[@id=\"did-ui-view\"]/div/section/section/form/section/div[1]/div/label/span[2]/input")
```

Please refer below document regarding String

[String Gude first Para](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/strings)